# django simple history field indexing

Tags: django, django-simple-history

How can I tell DSH to index particular field? Some queries that I do to historical models take too much time

[image]

I've base abstract model and all my models inherit from that model. The history field is also defined in this base model:

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    class PublishingStatus(models.TextChoices):
        DRAFT = 'draft', _('Draft')
        ACCEPTED = 'accepted', _('Accepted'),
        REJECTED = 'rejected', _('Rejected'),
        MODIFIED = 'modified', _('Modified')

    publishing_status = models.CharField(
        max_length=9,
        choices=PublishingStatus.choices,
        default=PublishingStatus.DRAFT,
        help_text=_("Publishing status represents the state of the object. By default it is 'draft'")
    )

    history = HistoricalRecords(inherit=True)
```

And I've also added indexes in this base model

```
class Meta:
    abstract = True
    indexes = [models.Index(fields=[
        'publishing_status',
    ])]
```

It would be nice if Django Simple History could check which fields are indexed and create the same indexes in the historical models

Maybe there is a way to tell django simple history explicitly which field must be indexed additionally?

Answer (score 0):

I hope there is a better solution, but I've ended up creating a custom migration file. First, I created a blank migration file for the app:

```
python manage.py makemigrations dosh --empty
```

I then modified this newly created empty migration file and added `AddIndex` for each historical model.

```
# Generated by Django 3.1.1 on 2020-10-15 06:49

from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('dosh', '0002_auto_20201008_2155'),
    ]

    operations = [
        # ...
        migrations.AddIndex(
            model_name='historicaltense',
            index=models.Index(fields=['publishing_status'], name='htense_publish_status_idx')
        ),
        migrations.AddIndex(
            model_name='historicalsynonym',
            index=models.Index(fields=['publishing_status'], name='hsynonym_publish_status_idx')
        ),
        # ...
    ]
```

And finally, I've migrated those changes

```
python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, authtoken, comment, contenttypes, dosh, pinax_badges, sessions, social, users, vote
Running migrations:
  Applying dosh.0003_auto_20201015_0849... OK
```